# Automatic logout

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Session is set to expire in 60 min, but it does not logout the user. This is how I tried to fix it, but it does not always work on published version.

```
public async void Logout(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider
       .GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        try
        {
            session_expires_at = DateTimeOffset.Parse(user.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "bff/session_expires_at").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault());
            session_expires_in = ((int)Math.Round(session_expires_at.Subtract(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow).TotalSeconds));
            Console.WriteLine(session_expires_at);
            Console.WriteLine(session_expires_in);
            if (session_expires_in < 2)
            {
                var url = user.FindFirst("bff/logout_url")?.Value;
                Navigation.NavigateTo(configuration["------"] + url, true);
            }
            else
                timer.Interval = session_expires_in > 30 ? (session_expires_in - 10) * 1000 : 1000;
        }
        catch { }
    });
}
```

Comment: What session, in what stack? Is this Windows Forms? WPF> WebForms? ASP.NET Classic MVC? Razor Pages? Blazor Server? Blazor WASM? What version? How do you *store* that session? How was the session configured?

Comment: BTW I can tell this is some flavor of Blazor but only because I was reading about Blazor security an hour ago. Especially the part that says *not* to use `AuthenticationStateProvider`, so you're already doing something unusual. There's no logout code in the question so one must assume that logout is performed by whatever handles `"bff/logout_url"` on the server. What does that code do? Are you using cookies, tokens? The server code should invalidate those cookies and tokens, forcing reauthentication on the next call. On the client, *your* code should clear those cookies/token

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.